# Using Middleware Laravel or using If session?

Tags: laravel

I'm create auth for " Admin " and " User " in laravel

What i'm should use ?

```
view.dashboard }
else if session == User {
view.paneluser 
}
```

or i must using middleware ?

What's different middleware and session ?

Comment: I wouldn't try to recreate the wheel and build your own authentication system if you're still learning what middleware is. I'd suggest using [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). Easy to integrate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sessions** are used to store information about the user across the requests.

**Middleware** acts as a bridge between a request and a response. It is a type of filtering mechanism

Middleware provides a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to the login screen.

but seems you want to call a method or action based on user role.